# How to Open .htm file in HTML page and Edit it?

Tags: html, editing

Can I open .htm file in HTML page and Edit it ?
e.g. using FrontPage inside HTML page to Open the .htm file and let one authorized user to modify contents of the .htm file, and then save the .htm file in the same folder from which the .htm file opened directly without searching for the folder ?

---

After Editing **************************

This is my code:
first HTML page

```
<li> <a target="_blank" href="1.htm">List1 </a></li>  

1.htm file:  

<frameset cols="50%,*">
    <frame name="contents" target="main" src="file_i_want_to_edit.htm">
    <frame name="main" src="1.pdf">
</frameset>
```

---

Thanks,

Ahmed.

Comment: Hi Ahmed can you write what you want to do in a series of numbered steps, it's not quite clear what you want to do.

Comment: Do you want to visually (WYSIWYG) edit the HTML or to see the source?
Anyway you'll need some server-side language (such as PHP, ASP etc.) to do this.

Comment: You can keep < and > if you highlight your code and click the "code" button in the editor when editing your question it will make things alot easier for everyone to read etc.

Comment: Still not quite sure what exactly you are asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave the user access to the folder in web server, and built a favorite menu so that he can go directly to the required folder, then right click on the file and Open With... and choose FrontPage or SharePoint editor.

Another solution, you can go to IIS and choose MIME map and create a new type which will open say .htm files with msword.

Thanks,

Ahmed.